# Partitioned table in publication and a non-partitioned table at subscriber in Sql Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication, transactional-replication

I was wondering whether we can use partitioned tables at the Publication level
and non-partitioned tables at the Subscriber level? I was reading this article,
[Replicating Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280940.aspx)

It doesn't mention anything about what if Publication has a partitioned table and subscribers are non-partitioned. Is it even possible? If yes how does it work? Because I have read somewhere that partition switch just changes the metadata of that partition. How would SQL Server know there’s new data to be replicated?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mixed setup, where the publisher has a partition setup the subscriber does not, then you cannot perform partition SWITCHES.  Doing so will result in a failure (due to the underlying associated transaction for the SWITCH, not being possible).

See the [Replication Support for Partition Switching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280940.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_1) section, bullet two:

> If the Subscriber has a different definition for the partitioned table than the Publisher, the Distribution Agent will fail when it tries to apply (SWITCH) changes at the Subscriber.

**Additional comments:**  This is not to imply that you CANNOT have a mix setup, just that you cannot perform a `SWITCH` on the publisher, IF it will impact/replicate to the subscribers.  During your article setup, [sp_addarticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173857.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), there are options for replicating partition schema and indexes, under the @schema_options